# UI does not display anything when a method is being called

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs, rest

**My setup:**

I want to call a java method which accepts a string from UI and **returns a JSON String**. This method takes 5+ seconds to compute and return the JSON String. This method is *not even being called* when I use UI to enter as argument: I confirmed this as some files are created locally which are not being created.

My project is setup with *AngularJS with Spring* which is working fine end to end.

**Setter Method:**

```
public void setBrand(String brand) {
this.brand  = AmazonReview.getAmazonReview(this.brand);
  }
```

**Getter Method:**

```
public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
  }
```

**AmazonReview Method** 
//**This is the method which does all the computation and returns JSON**

```
public static String getAmazonReview(String s){
...;
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./something.pl com " + id);
...;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("product1", l1);
return obj.toJSONString();
}
```

**Front-end**

I'm just taking input from user (in text box) Nothing fancy here!

```
<form novalidate class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="save()">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="brand">Brand</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="brand.brand" id="brand"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Brand Description</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="brandDescription">Brand Description</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" ng-model="brand.brandDescription.brandDescription" id="brandDescription"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module("sprang", ["sprang.services"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/brands', {templateUrl: '/views/brands/list.html', controller: BrandListController})
            .when('/brands/:brandId', {templateUrl: '/views/brands/detail.html', controller: BrandDetailController});
    });

function BrandListController($scope, Brand) {
        $scope.brands = Brand.query();
        $scope.deleteBrand = function(brand) {
            brand.$delete(function() {
                $scope.brands.splice($scope.brands.indexOf(brand),1);
                toastr.success("Deleted");
            });
        }
    }

function BrandDetailController($scope, $routeParams, $location, Brand) {
        var brandId = $routeParams.brandId;
        if (brandId === 'new') {
            $scope.brand = new Brand();
        } else {
            $scope.brand = Brand.get({brandId: brandId});
        }
        $scope.save = function () {
            if ($scope.brand.isNew()) {
                $scope.brand.$save(function (brand, headers) {
                    toastr.success("Created");
                    var location = headers('Location');
                    var id = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    $location.path('/brands/' + id);
                });
            } else {
                $scope.brand.$update(function() {
                    toastr.success("Updated");
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

**My issue:**

1) If I replace the method code with just **return "Hello"**; **my UI is displaying Hello**.

2) I just wanted to display the JSON(String) back to frontend. But it's not even running the method to let me do that.

Thanks for your help!

To sum up, When I call my slow java method in eclipse (from another java program), *I get the expected JSON* but when I do the same with UI (AngularJS), *the method is not being called*.

Comment: I assume `Brand` is an angular service?  Post the code for it.

Comment: Hello,

I figured out the solution, json-simple was the culprit. I removed everything and I can see that even though my method takes a little time, the UI still waits and it's displayed. (i don't know any better way to explain this :P). In short, if I remove JSON-simple it works!